# Determine IQueryable column type based on name

Tags: linq, types, iqueryable

I have an iQueryable dataset.

I wish to be able to determine the type of data based on the name.

I am doing a linq query into a view model and I wish to get the type of column by name from the resulting query

Comment: The type you mean the SQL Server type, or the C# type?

Comment: Either would work, I need to determine if a column is an integer or string by name not by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IQueryable q = ...;
if (q.ElementType.GetProperty("PropertyName").PropertyType == typeof(int))
{
    // PropertyName is an integer property
    . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly clear what you are asking... I do hope you don't want to discover that `Id` and `IdChild` and `ChildId` are `int` just because they contain the word `Id`...

For a more sane "you give me the query and the name of the property, I give you the `Type` of the property":

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static Type TypeOf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName);

        return property != null ? property.PropertyType : null;
    }

    public static Type TypeOf<TSource, TType>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TType> property)
    {
        return typeof(TType);
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
Type type = query.TypeOf("Id");
```

or if you are using the non-generic `IQueryable`, use @shevchenko's solution